# How to disable wss4j timestamp cache

Tags: soap, wss4j

I need to update a javaEE application (still in java 1.7) that provides a SOAP web service. And I'd like to disable the *TIMESTAMP_CACHE* that wss4j (v2.0.2) uses to control [reply attacks](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/newfeatures20.html). It creates too many files and the OS reaches the maximum open files allowed, repeatedly. The files start to appear, one for each request that has been made and are named in the following way:

> wss4j%002etimestamp%002ecache-e%0058ga%0058l%0058%004b%0057g%004ah%0050w==.data

The [documentation](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html) states that the *TIMESTAMP_CACHE* can be changed (or so I understand):

> ConfigurationConstants.ENABLE_TIMESTAMP_CACHE ("enableTimestampCache"): Whether to cache Timestamp Created Strings (these are only cached in conjunction with a message Signature). The default value is "true".

I've found many examples to change some of these *ConfigurationConstants* when a client application creates the Call object. See an example to change the *PASSWORD_TYPE* constant:

```
Service service = new Service(); 
Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
...  
call.setProperty(UsernameToken.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);  
call.setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.USER,"werner");
```

However, my application is not on the client side but on the server side and I haven't found so far the way to change the *ENABLE_TIMESTAMP_CACHE* constant.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to disable the timestamp cache. However, the wss4j behaviour described above happened to be a bug that not only resulted in lots of open files but in lots of open threads. It has already been fixed in version 2.0.9. Upgrading to the "newer" version did the trick.

You can find here the [discussion in full that drove to the bug discovery](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@ws.apache.org/msg00409.html) and here the [fix in wss4j's jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-584)